# How to get Request.Scheme property outside of the controller . .(Net Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Whilst attempting to generate urls from outside of my controller , I'm  unable to get at  `Request.Scheme`.
In the controller i can do this to generate a url without problems:

```
   //get UserManager bits
    var callBackUrl = Url.CallBackExtensionLink(user.Id, token, Request.Scheme);
```

`CallBackExtensionLink()` is an `IUrlHelper` extension method that i created.
However,Request.Scheme throws a null reference exception.
How can I get the value outside of the controller ?

Comment: _"How can I get the value outside of the controller"_ - by getting the request via an instance of [HttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.ihttpcontextaccessor.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Comment: I'm able to get the scheme via the HttpContextAccessor by just injecting it into the constructor of my class , however i still get an error `helper object is null`. So I think the issue is also down to accessing the `IUrlHelper` object

Comment: Please share the code of your extension method and where you call this method?

Answer (score 1):

So after some more investigating I was able to mitigate this problem by injecting `IUrlHelper` into the DI in .net core which is done differently to how others are done.

add this to the DI :

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper>(x => {
                var actionContext = x.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
                var factory = x.GetRequiredService<IUrlHelperFactory>();
                return factory.GetUrlHelper(actionContext);
            });
```

And then pass IUrlHelper into the implementing class constructor.

```
private readonly IUrlHelper helper;

    YourConstructor(IUrlHelper helper){
    
    this.helper = helper;
    }
```